# datetime - разница в сутки

Tags: python, дата, datetime

Необходимо определить, имеется ли между текущей датой и пришедшей датой разница в сутки.

```
def gt(dt_str):
    print(dt_str)
    dt, _, us = dt_str.partition(".")
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    us = int(us.rstrip("Z"), 10)
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=us)

def isToday(text):
    current = gt(text)
    curr = datetime.datetime.now()
    period = curr - current
    # print(current)
    # print(curr)
    if(period.total_seconds() >= 86400):
        return False
    return True
```

Данный код хорошо работает для дат формата

```
2020-04-26T13:30:04.000Z
```

Но иногда прилетает

```
2020-04-26T02:51:47Z
```

Как можно конвертировать и такие даты.
Использую Python 3.6

Comment: Используйте библиотеку [iso8601](https://pypi.org/project/iso8601/)

Comment: @andreymal TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes при вычитании

Comment: `cur = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=iso8601.UTC)`

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо, можете добавить как ответ

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
In [80]: from dateutil.parser import parse as dt_parse   # pip install dateutil

In [81]: dt_parse("2020-04-26T13:30:04.000Z")
Out[81]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 13, 30, 4, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [82]: dt_parse("2020-04-26T02:51:47Z")
Out[82]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 2, 51, 47, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [83]: dt_parse("2020-04-26T03:03:03.123456Z")
Out[83]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 3, 3, 3, 123456, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [84]: dt_parse("2020-04-26T03:03:03.123456GMT+2")
Out[84]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 3, 3, 3, 123456, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -7200))
```

---

**UPDATE:** для того чтобы работала арифметика - **обе** даты должны быть либо `offset-aware` либо `offset-naive`:

offset-aware:

```
In [99]: from datetime import timezone, datetime as DT

In [100]: DT.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) - dt_parse("2020-04-26T03:03:03.123456Z").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
Out[100]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=46843, microseconds=764721)
```

offset-naive:

```
In [101]: DT.now() - dt_parse("2020-04-26T03:03:03.123456Z").replace(tzinfo=None)
Out[101]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=54144, microseconds=524074)
```